# ng-repeat shows another ng-repeat data

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am trying to show up 2 menu's

1. Deparments -> subdepartments
2. List item

onclick of "event" button

1. should show up. onclick of "dates", button
2. should show up.

Here the issue is both  the 1) and 2) display in single menu though both the htmls are different. Where am i going wrong.Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="tab" >
                <div class="sidebar-top">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Date</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                     <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">

                         <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                            <li class=" nav-active active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>

                            <li class="nav-parent" ng-repeat="(key, value) in getdatewasedetails | groupBy: 'depatName'">
                              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><span></span>{{ key }} <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                              <ul class="children collapse" ng-repeat="subdept in value">
                                <li ><a href="#"> {{ subdept.serviceName }}  </a></li>

                              </ul>
                            </li>

                         </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">

                         <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                            <li class=" nav-active active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>

                            <li class="nav-parent" ng-repeat="(key, value) in getdatewasedetails| groupBy: 'month'">
                              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i><span></span>{{ key | date:'MMMM' : 'UTC' }} <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                              <ul class="children collapse" ng-repeat="currDates in value">
                                <li ><a href="#"> {{currDates.testDate  | date:'longDate' : 'UTC'}}  </a></li>

                              </ul>
                            </li>

                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>    

            </div>
```

**Resulted Json:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Angular JS:**

```
 $scope.lastVisit = function () {

            var request = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "dashboardServiceCall.php",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            });
            /* Successful HTTP get request or not */
            request.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                z=0;
                for(var x=0; x < data.length; x++){

                if(data[x]['type'] == 3){

                    for(var g=0; g<data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'].length; g++){
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][g];
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate = new Date($scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate);
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].category = data[x]['data']['panelName'];
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].month = $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate.getMonth();

                    z++;
                    }

                    for(var y=0; y<data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'].length; y++){

                    for(var d=0; d< data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'].length; d++){ 
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][d];
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate = new Date($scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate);    
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].category = data[x]['data']['panelName'];           
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].month = $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate.getMonth();                      
                    z++;
                    }

                }

                }else if(data[x]['type'] == 1 ){



                    for(var g=0; g<data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'].length; g++){
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][g];
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate = new Date($scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate);
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].category = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][g]['serviceName'];
                    $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].month = $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate.getMonth();
                    z++;
                    }
                }else if(data[x]['type'] == 2){

                for(var y=0; y<data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'].length; y++){

                    for(var d=0; d< data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'].length; d++){ 
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][d];
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate = new Date($scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate);
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].category = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['groupName'];      
                        $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].month = $scope.getdatewasedetails[z].testDate.getMonth();                      
                    z++;
                    }

                }
                }

                }



                $scope.leftNavMenu = $scope.getdatewasedetails;



            });


    }
```

Above two images show output.both the ng-repeats are rendering. i am not sure where am i going wrong.Any help would be great. thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle to it?

Comment: Can you show use your json data which you're rendering through ng-repeat and show us your angular code as well.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: @3bu1, a JSFiddle would also be appreciated, so we know what your classes do. There might be a problem there.

Comment: @NunoM data is a web service call...i think it is not possible to give a fiddle...will try once with dummy data

Comment: You can check the data given to you by the API of a web service. Is that what you mean by "it's a web service I can't make a fiddle"?  Open the API link in browser and check the data. For Chrome (similar in others), you can also F12 and then click Network tab to see what has been passed. Find your file in a list, refresh if you have to, and select it. Response subtab should hold the response in any form given. Maybe your data is wrong. If it's correct, maybe error lies when you try to parse data into JSON. Debug your app at the point after data has been made into objects and see.

Comment: Added angular code.@DanteTheSmith we have base64 auth enabled i cannot seee data in browser.